# After Record Update still Displaying Old Record

Tags: jquery

I use jquery post() to update a database record. Then a get() from the same function to display the updated record to a div. However the get() still returns the old record. I have tried load() but still get the same results.

```
function update_RecordDetails() {
    $.post("_assets/update_RecordDetails.asp", {
        recorddetailid:  $('#recorddetailid').val(),
        findings: $('#findings').val()
    },
    function(data, status){
        $("#alert").html(data);
    });
    $.get('_assets/execute_RecordDetails.asp?recordid=' + $('#recordid').val(), function(result) {
        $('#treatments_div').val(result);
    });             
}
```

Comment: You understand that ajax calls are asynchronous, correct?  As such both your post request and your get request will be executing around the same time.  Your get request will *NOT* wait for your post to finish.  You can try moving your get request into the success method of your post request so it will only happen once your post finishes successfully.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for your help:)